# At each subtotal, for then loop copy and paste above data vba

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, copy-paste

I am trying to copy each subtotal and paste above each data set using the *for then* loop. Maybe there is a more appropriate loop to use here I am not 100% sure. I am having trouble getting the loop to copy the subtotal after the condition is met. See code below:

```
For I = 1000 To 2 Step -1 ' adjust 1000 to the row number of the last element
If Cells(I, 7).Font.Bold Then
    Cells(I + 1, 1).Copy
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Selection.Offset(1, -7).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next
```

What I can't get the macro to do is copy the actual subtotal, it doesn't even copy the cell it was selected. In case you need to see what I'm trying to get the loop to do see pic below.

[image]

Comment: This can be done without programming if you're interested. Just click level-2 button in the left side-bar (showing 3 levels of sub-totals). This will collapse the sheet to sub-totals rows only. Then select and copy-paste things to wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cells(I + 1, 1).Copy` is correctly copying the cell contents, but it isn't actually selecting the cell.  Then you are trying to set the destination by moving the selection starting with the selected cell, but the starting point for `selection` hasn't actually been set by the loop in the first place.

One way to change it is to not use `.select` until it is time to paste.  This is also more efficient because `.select` is very inefficient and should be minimized.

```
For I = 1000 To 2 Step -1 ' adjust 1000 to the row number of the last element
If Cells(I, 7).Font.Bold Then
    Cells(I + 1, 7).Copy
    Cells(I + 1, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -6).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
Next
```

Comment: I got a "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the end(xlUp).Offset line

Comment: I've updated the code snippet -- there was an error to copy the cell in column 1 and then offset -7 columns, which is of course off the spreadsheet and produces the error you saw.  This should avoid the error, but I'm not sure it copies exactly the cell you want.  Adjust the cells(I + 1, 7) and the offset(1, -6) to get the outcome you are looking for.

Comment: Great that worked thanks! Is there a way for me to have it skip if the Cells(I,7) value = "Grand Total" ? Should I nest another if in the if statement?

Comment: yes, you could just add that condition `If Cells(I, 7).Font.Bold and Cells(I, 7) <> "Grand Total" Then` ...